# shell/bash: use sed/awk to get string between special characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

suppose I have a string as

```
Al99.NegFRho.ZeroRhoR.ZeroPhiR.eam.alloy
```

I want to get 3 strings between 2 dots

```
NegFRho
ZeroRhoR
ZeroPhiR
```

how can I do it with sed or awk?

Comment: `echo Al99.NegFRho.ZeroRhoR.ZeroPhiR.eam.alloy | cut -d. --output-delimiter=' ' -f2-4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
str='Al99.NegFRho.ZeroRhoR.ZeroPhiR.eam.alloy'
awk -F. -v OFS='\n' '{print $2, $3, $4}' <<< "$str"

NegFRho
ZeroRhoR
ZeroPhiR
```

Another smaller awk variant using `RS`:

```
awk -v RS=. 'NR>=2 && NR<=4' <<< "$str"

NegFRho
ZeroRhoR
ZeroPhiR
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed, you'd use

```
$ sed 's/^[^.]*\.\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*\)\..*/\1\n\2\n\3/' <<<"$str"
NegFRho
ZeroRhoR
ZeroPhiR
```

Or, GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '\.\K[^.]+'  <<<"$str" | head -3
NegFRho
ZeroRhoR
ZeroPhiR
```